# change progress bar span text on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 collapsing tabs which each display 5 progress bars on each tab. I would like for the progress bar percentage e.g. '79%', to change to show grade e.g. 'B+' when a user hovers over the bar. How can I achieve this?

2nd question: I want to make each tab collapse the other tab e.g. when I select 'Semester 1' I want 'Semester 2' to be hidden and vise versa. If I close 'Semester 1' I want 'Semester 2' to show etc.

https://jsfiddle.net/oed6vbt9/

code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



  <section id="education" style="background-color:whitesmoke;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row d-flex no-gutters">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto">
          <h2 style="text-align: center;"> Education </h2>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div class="pull-left" style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.801);">
            <h3>BSc in Computing</h3>
            <br>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <br>
            <br>

            <div class="col-md-4 disabled">

              <div class="tu-icon">
                <a target="_blank" href="https://www.it-tallaght.ie/">
                  <img class="mx-auto mb-2" src="tudub.png" alt="about"
                    style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border:2px solid #000000">
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-md-8">

              <!--nav tabs-->
              <div class="tabs">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                  <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#first" data-toggle="tab"> First Year </a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#second" data-toggle="tab"> Second Year </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!--Start single tab content-->
              <div class="tab-content">

                <div class="service-box tab-pane fade in active row show" id="first">
                  <div class="contents">

                    <div class="section-title">
                      <br>
                      <h4 style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.801);"> First Year</h4>
                      <br>
                    </div>



                    <div class="col-md-8 animate-box">




                      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
                        <!--Collapse Semester 1-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default show">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Semester 1</a>
                            </h4>
                          </div>
                          <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in show">
                            <div class="panel-body">

                              <!--progress bars-->

                              <h5>Software Development B+</h5>
                              <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="progress-bar  color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="79"
                                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:79%">
                                  <span>79%</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              <h5>Business Information Systems B</h5>
                              <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="progress-bar  color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="69"
                                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:69%">
                                  <span>69%</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              <h5>Visual Design B-</h5>
                              <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="progress-bar  color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="59"
                                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:59%">
                                  <span>59%</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              <h5>Systems Analysis B</h5>
                              <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="progress-bar  color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="69"
                                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:69%">
                                  <span>69%</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              <h5>Statistics B</h5>
                              <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="progress-bar  color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="69"
                                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:69%">
                                  <span>69%</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>



                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--Collapse Semester 2-->
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                          <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Semester 2</a>
                            </h4>
                          </div>
                          <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">

                              <!--progress bars-->


                              <h5>Software Development 2 B</h5>
                              <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="progress-bar  color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="68"
                                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:68%">
                                  <span>68%</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              <h5>Introduction to Operating Systems B</h5>
                              <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="progress-bar  color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="69"
                                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:69%">
                                  <span>69%</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              <h5>Web and Datasbase Fundementals B-</h5>
                              <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="progress-bar  color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="59"
                                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:59%">
                                  <span>59%</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              <h5>Discrete Mathematics B-</h5>
                              <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="progress-bar  color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="59"
                                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:59%">
                                  <span>59%</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>
                              <h5>Systems Analysis 2 B</h5>
                              <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                                <div class="progress-bar  color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="69"
                                  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:69%">
                                  <span>69%</span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <br>


                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                      </div>






                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--End single tab content-->
                <!--Start single tab content-->
                <div class="service-box tab-pane fade in" id="second">
                  <div class="contents">

                    <div class="section-title">
                      <br>
                      <h3> Second Year</h3>
                      <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8 animate-box">
                      <div class="progress-wrap">
                        <h3>Java</h3>
                        <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                          <div class="progress-bar color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0"
                            aria-valuemax="100" style="width:90%">
                            <span>90%</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <br>

                      <div class="progress-wrap ftco-animate">
                        <h3>C#</h3>
                        <div class="progress">
                          <div class="progress-bar color-2" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0"
                            aria-valuemax="100" style="width:85%">
                            <span>85%</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <br>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--End single tab content-->



              </div>


            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

css:

```
section {
  padding: 150px 0;
}

header {
  padding: 156px 0 100px;
}

.it-icons a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  background-color: #4582EC;
  color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.it-icons a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3) rotate(20deg);
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.tu-icon a:hover {
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}


.os-icons a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  background-color: #4582EC;
  color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.os-icons a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3) rotate(20deg);
  background-color: skyblue;
}




.tabs .nav-tabs > li, .tabs .nav-pills > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 2px solid #4582EC;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #4582EC;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li a:hover {
  background: #4582EC;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #4582EC;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li.active a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #4582EC;
  border: 2px solid #4582EC;
}

.service-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.service-box .contents {
  margin-left: 30px;
}



.tab-content {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.service-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.service-box .section-title h3 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.service-box .section-title h3:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
  background: #333333;
  height: 1px;
  width: 55px;
}
```

Comment: If this is a static site (as the grade being filled in in the `aria-valuenow` leads me to believe; it isn't set with JS), why not just set the `title` attribute to the appropriate grade? Then the hovering stuff will be done for you, since browsers show `title` when hovering.

Comment: @matthew-e-brown, I could do that although it does not look as visually pleasing to the eye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 2 elements inside `.progress-bar`, one for percentage and one for grade. Then hide one by default. Then toggle visibility based on parent hover.

```css
.progress .progress-bar > span {
  position:relative;
  height:100%;
}
.progress .progress-bar > span > * {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
}

.progress .grade {
  opacity:0;
}

.progress:hover .grade {
  opacity:1;
}

.progress:hover .percentage {
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="progress-bar  color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="79"
    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:79%">
    <span><span class="percentage">79%</span><span class="grade">B+</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```